# Export from database to JSON file

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I need to export data from the database to a JSON file.
The following is the code I have used to store the JSON file to the database

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\FilesTest\Dump\sample1.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
```

The code above saves the JSON data in the database table. I need the code that can export that data back to a JSON file, in a specified path when I call it. The JSON file should look like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "detail": "Verification Successful",
    "data": {
        "Number": "000001900019",
        "Batchnumber": "677899 444404",
        "Linked": "9",
        "FullName": "Tuoyo Dante",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "LinkedEmail": null,
        "PerformanceSummary": [
            {
                "BALANCE": "0",
                "AMOUNT": "EUR   0",
                "OVERDUE_AMOUNT": "0"
            },
            {
                "BALANCE": "0",
                "AMOUNT": "EUR   2,000",
                "OVERDUE_AMOUNT": "0"
            },
            {
                "BALANCE": "8,256",
                "AMOUNT": "EUR   6,350,020",
                "OVERDUE_AMOUNT": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include your best attempt to the question.

Comment: Confused: if you are just saving and loading a `varchar` blob then who cares what format it has, just use `sqlcmd` to output the blob to file? But if you need to generate JSON from actual table resultsets, how do you expect to do this with SQL Server 2008, which has no JSON support? Perhaps it's time to upgrade

Comment: @Charlieface
Thanks. I guess i need to upgrade too and i am considering moving to MSSQL 2016 soonest. However, i found a way to export from SQL 2008 to a JSON file using a stored procedure.
Thanks so much for your help and comments